# Javascript PHP String not returning desired results

Tags: javascript, php

I am using this javascript or PHP to convert a database field into a string so that I can sort on that column, however when the value of the database is null - the sorting is screwed up because I get a weird value around 1970 for the year

Does anyone know how to fix this ??

```
$movie_str = date('Ymd', strtotime($row['CD_MOVIE']));
```

Comment: Can you give us the content of `$row['CD_MOVIE']` and the actual weird value

Comment: *I am using this javascript to convert a database...* -  Er... Where's the JavaScript?

Comment: maybe its PHP - not sure

Comment: @Rus that's kind of important. Start with is it a .php file or a .js file?

Comment: @Rus It **is** PHP. I guess you need to replace `Ymd` with `Y/m/d`?

Comment: "weird value around 1970" means that strtotime() failed, returned boolean false, which was then type-cast to an integer 0 for date(), which then converted it to the epoch, Jan 1/1970

Comment: @Rus : It's hard to tell what exactly went wrong without you telling us what value is inside `$row['CD_MOVIE']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do when your value is null, you could do something like

```
$val = $row['CD_MOVIE'];
$movie_str = (!is_null($val)) ? date('Ymd', strtotime($val)) : "0";
```

Comment: I just want the value to be '0'

Comment: I changed my answer :)

Comment: Could be shortened to: `$movie_str = (!is_null($val)) ? date('Ymd', strtotime($val)) : 0;`